# Hibernate static SQL?

Tags: hibernate, db2

Is it possible for Hibernate to be configured to generate static SQL?
Is there a Hibernate configuration/set-up parameter that forces Hibernate to generate static SQL as opposed to dynamic?
Can not find this in any manuals I have looked at. 
I am working with Hibernate in a DB2 environment and trying to find ways of improving application performance.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via PureQuery, a recent IBM product that generates the SQL from Hibernate, and then you can create a package for static SQL.

There is an excellent tutorial for this in DeveloperWorks: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1008hibernateibatispurequery1/index.html

Remember that you can download a Optim PureQuery trial version for 90 days.